# MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch on AWS EC2 Windows Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I've reached a point of defeat, basically I've tried to setup the MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch on Windows Server 2012 running on Amazon AWS EC2 and failed miserably.

I have similar setup already running fine on Windows Server 2008 (running on dedicated box) which is as follows:

- MongoDB 2.6.3 setup on Linux box (that didn't change)
- ES 1.1.1 on Windows box (fresh new Windows Server 2012)
- both on completely different networks.

Now the issue is that I'm getting some exceptions and River is not pulling any data to ES:

```
[http.netty] [Spider-Slayer] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x9fa1daca, /127.0.0.1:57260 => /127.0.0.1:9200] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
```

It seems like River can't connect to DB or send the data back to ES. There isn't a lot of debugging information in logs except that river failed to start.

I suspect that publish address for ES isn't correct or blocked (don't know really how to debug that).

Any help how to get this working or debugged greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is my CMD output when started fresh (deleted index, river and data directory then tried to create index and river this cropped up)

```
[2015-04-16 15:50:12,001][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Stardust] [_river] update_mapping [index_name] (dynamic)
[2015-04-16 15:50:12,587][TRACE][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Initializing river : [index_name]
[2015-04-16 15:50:12,859][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] Parse river settings for index_name
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,132][TRACE][river.mongodb            ] mongoServersSettings: [{port=27017, host=linux_box_ip}]
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,216][INFO ][river.mongodb            ] Server: linux_box_ip - 27017
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,481][TRACE][river.mongodb            ] mongoOptionsSettings: {secondary_read_preference=true}
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,770][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Starting river index_name
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,804][DEBUG][river.mongodb.util       ] setRiverStatus called with index_name - RUNNING
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,865][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Stardust] [_river] update_mapping [index_name] (dynamic)
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,880][DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Using mongodb server(s): host [linux_box_ip], port [27017]
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,965][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.0] - hash[a0c23f1] - time[2014-02-23T20:40:05Z]
[2015-04-16 15:50:13,994][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] starting mongodb stream. options: secondaryreadpreference [true], drop_collection [false], include_collection [], throttl
esize [5000], gridfs [false], filter [null], db [db_name], collection [entities], script [null], indexing to [index_name]/[entity]
[2015-04-16 15:50:15,170][TRACE][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] MongoAdminUser:  - authenticated: false
[2015-04-16 15:50:15,359][TRACE][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Found admin database
[2015-04-16 15:50:15,543][TRACE][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] About to execute: { "serverStatus" : 1 , "asserts" : 0 , "backgroundFlushing" : 0 , "connections" : 0 , "cursors" : 0 , "
dur" : 0 , "extra_info" : 0 , "globalLock" : 0 , "indexCounters" : 0 , "locks" : 0 , "metrics" : 0 , "network" : 0 , "opcounters" : 0 , "opcountersRepl" : 0 , "recordStats" : 0 , "repl" : 0}
Apr 16, 2015 3:50:36 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: user/77.x.x.x:27017 <-- THIS IP IS DIFFERENT THAN MONGODB SERVER IP !!!
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:223)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:125)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:106)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:162)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:170)
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode.update(ConnectionStatus.java:196)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$UpdatableReplicaSetNode.update(ReplicaSetStatus.java:603)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Updater.updateAll(ReplicaSetStatus.java:755)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Updater.run(ReplicaSetStatus.java:725)

[2015-04-16 15:50:56,785][WARN ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver] Fail to start river index_name
com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find a master
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:517)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:236)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:262)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:244)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:301)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:199)
        at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.isMongos(MongoDBRiver.java:264)
        at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.start(MongoDBRiver.java:208)
        at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService.createRiver(RiversService.java:148)
        at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:275)
        at org.elasticsearch.river.RiversService$ApplyRivers$2.onResponse(RiversService.java:269)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$1.run(TransportAction.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-04-16 15:50:56,872][DEBUG][river.mongodb.util       ] setRiverStatus called with index_name - START_FAILED
[2015-04-16 15:50:56,961][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Stardust] [_river] update_mapping [index_name] (dynamic)
```

EDIT 2:

rs.status() output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-17T11:12:38.000Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "name:27017",
            "health" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 1.8122e+007,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1429269108, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-17T11:11:48.000Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1411147182, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2014-09-19T17:19:42.000Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Comment: What do you get from `rs.status()` ?

Comment: @thegreenogre I've just added the output to the question. All seems to be working fine on MongoDB side (it's still powering other services and feeding data to the other setup mentioned above).